# Sorting a table wrt to last two elements

Tags: sorting

I have a table-1 having 36 elements, each having the form {A, m, n}, where m & n are the indices (1-6).

There is another table-2 having 36 elements {m, n} in a particular order (like {{4, 3}, {2, 3}....} etc.).

I want to arrange the elements of first table in a way that it follows the same order of m & n as in table 2. How can I achieve it. Thanks

Comment: I would look at the `Ordering` function -- you should be able to get something like `Ordering[table2[[All, 2;;3]]]` then apply that ordering to table 1. [link](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html?q=Ordering)

Answer (score 2):

Fake data:

```
table1 = Prepend[#, A] & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 6}, {10, 2}]
table2 = Tuples[Range[6], 2]
```

Sort table1 by table2 positions:

```
SortBy[table1, Position[table2, #[[2 ;; 3]]] &]
```

Answer (score 2):

Fleshing out @user16054's suggestion, here is an example table 1 and an example target:

```
SeedRandom[1];
table1 = Flatten /@ Thread[{
    Array[a, 36],
    Tuples[Range[6], 2][[PermutationList @ RandomPermutation @ SymmetricGroup[36]]]
}]

target = Tuples[Range[6], 2][[PermutationList @ RandomPermutation @ SymmetricGroup[36]]]
```

> {{a[1], 4, 3}, {a[2], 1, 2}, {a[3], 1, 3}, {a[4], 2, 1}, {a[5], 6, 
>     5}, {a[6], 2, 5}, {a[7], 6, 2}, {a[8], 5, 2}, {a[9], 5, 6}, {a[10], 
>     3, 4}, {a[11], 2, 2}, {a[12], 5, 1}, {a[13], 3, 6}, {a[14], 6, 
>     3}, {a[15], 2, 6}, {a[16], 1, 6}, {a[17], 5, 4}, {a[18], 4, 
>     2}, {a[19], 4, 5}, {a[20], 2, 4}, {a[21], 4, 6}, {a[22], 6, 
>     1}, {a[23], 3, 5}, {a[24], 3, 1}, {a[25], 5, 3}, {a[26], 1, 
>     1}, {a[27], 6, 4}, {a[28], 5, 5}, {a[29], 6, 6}, {a[30], 4, 
>     4}, {a[31], 2, 3}, {a[32], 4, 1}, {a[33], 3, 2}, {a[34], 3, 
>     3}, {a[35], 1, 4}, {a[36], 1, 5}}
>
> {{3, 1}, {3, 4}, {5, 5}, {4, 4}, {1, 3}, {4, 6}, {1, 2}, {6, 5}, {2, 
>     2}, {1, 5}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {5, 2}, {3, 5}, {2, 5}, {1, 6}, {5, 
>     1}, {3, 6}, {2, 6}, {6, 1}, {4, 3}, {2, 1}, {6, 4}, {3, 3}, {4, 
>     1}, {6, 3}, {5, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 1}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 6}, {5, 
>     4}, {2, 4}, {6, 2}, {4, 2}}

Then, determine the ordering of `table1` and `target`:

```
ord1 = Ordering[table1[[All, 2;;]]]
ordt = Ordering[target]
```

> {26, 2, 3, 35, 36, 16, 4, 11, 31, 20, 6, 15, 24, 33, 34, 10, 23, 13, 32, 18, 1, 30, 19, 21, 12, 8, 25, 17, 28, 9, 22, 7, 14, 27, 5, 29}
>
> {29, 7, 5, 28, 10, 16, 22, 9, 11, 34, 15, 19, 1, 12, 24, 2, 14, 18, 25, 36, 21, 4, 30, 6, 17, 13, 27, 33, 3, 31, 20, 35, 26, 23, 8, 32}

Finally, invert `ordt` and use the inverse and `ord1` to reorder table 1:

```
res = table1[[ord1[[InversePermutation @ ordt]]]]
```

> {{a[24], 3, 1}, {a[10], 3, 4}, {a[28], 5, 5}, {a[30], 4, 4}, {a[3], 1, 
>     3}, {a[21], 4, 6}, {a[2], 1, 2}, {a[5], 6, 5}, {a[11], 2, 2}, {a[36], 1, 
>     5}, {a[31], 2, 3}, {a[33], 3, 2}, {a[8], 5, 2}, {a[23], 3, 5}, {a[6], 2, 
>     5}, {a[16], 1, 6}, {a[12], 5, 1}, {a[13], 3, 6}, {a[15], 2, 6}, {a[22], 6, 
>     1}, {a[1], 4, 3}, {a[4], 2, 1}, {a[27], 6, 4}, {a[34], 3, 3}, {a[32], 4, 
>     1}, {a[14], 6, 3}, {a[25], 5, 3}, {a[35], 1, 4}, {a[26], 1, 1}, {a[19], 4, 
>     5}, {a[9], 5, 6}, {a[29], 6, 6}, {a[17], 5, 4}, {a[20], 2, 4}, {a[7], 6, 
>     2}, {a[18], 4, 2}}

The output above is ordered in the same way as target.